# Python Pandas figsize not defined

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am new to pandas for data analysis and I just installed pandas with required dependencies (NumPy, python-dateutil, pytz, numexpr, bottleneck and matplotlib). But when I started trying the most basic code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') # Make the graphs a bit prettier
figsize(15, 5)
```

It complains NameError: name 'figsize' is not defined.

I am not sure if I still need some other dependencies. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: where did you get this example from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham from the offical pandas tutorial:http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%201%20-%20Reading%20from%20a%20CSV.ipynb

Comment: you must insert this cell : fixDf.plot(figsize=(15, 5))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `%pylab` if  `%pylab inline` does not work.

So it should be:

```
 %pylab
 import pandas as pd
 pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') # Make the graphs a bit prettier
 figsize(15, 5)
```

The example is based on running the code in Ipython using Ipython magic command `%pylab` which gives you:

```
In [16]: %pylab
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
```

If you are not using Ipython and the `%pylab` magic you will have to use something like:

```
from pylab import *
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15,5
```

If you have Ipython-notebook istalled you can start it with pylab inline using:

```
ipython notebook --pylab inline from the command line.
```

I would recommend using Ipython to start with.

This is a link to the Ipython commands [quick reference](http://damontallen.github.io/IPython-quick-ref-sheets/)

Comment: do you mean add %pylab on the top of code (including the % sign)? But it returned invalid syntax? Am I using it wrong?

Comment: no, I just put them in a normal code.py file and run it from command line like python code.py. I have Ipython installed but no idea what does it mean running in IPython?

Comment: Hi Padraic, thanks, it is the first time I try iPython, it looks cool! I can type directly in terminal %pylab and execute figsize(15,5), which is working. But when I executed %run code.py with "%pylab" in the file, it returns "%" is invalid syntax. Please tell me the right way to do it.

Comment: you don't put %pylab in your file. Just enter it in the console to activate the pylab magic. if you want to enter code into the Ipython you can copy the code and type `paste` into the console. Just copy the code not any Ipython magic command.

Answer (score 6):

When I got the same problem I changed figsize() from function call to assignment  figsize = (15,5)
And it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You might be using an earlier version of pandas. The function `figsize()` may have been introduced in a later version.

In version 1.13 I achieved something similar with a statement like `df.plot(figsize=(15, 5))`

Answer (score 0):

using `VarianleName.plot(figszie=(n,n)` will solve the problem 
`n,n` could be `numbers` like `15,10`
[image: Using Plot Figure Size]